# Only save the records that don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Currently I am grabbing football fixtures via a screen scrape and each time the rake task is performed I am deleting all the records and saving the new ones..I don't want to do this, I want to only save the fixtures that dont exist. My logic so far is

```
def get_fixtures # Get me all Home and away Teams
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
 days = doc.css('#fixtures-data h2').each do |h2_tag|
 date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip).to_date
  matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.preview')
  matches.each do |match|
    home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
    away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
    kick_off = match.css('td.kickoff').text.strip
     Fixture.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date, kickoff_time: kick_off)
 end
end
```

end

What would be the best way to go about this, another method to check if record exists? but unsure how to go about this

My fixture model

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :fixture_date, :kickoff_time, :prediction_id

  belongs_to :predictions
end
```

could i use validates_uniqueness_of in the fixture model, would my create in the rake task check this first?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several choices:

One Shot (as of Rails 3.2.13):

```
Fixture.where(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date, kickoff_time: kick_off).first_or_create!
```

Comment: thanks, does this have any consequences with regards to speed?

Comment: @Richlewis, minor bump due to checking if record exists first. However is that a concern for this task? If so, you can use straight SQL. In mysql's case, use "INSERT IGNORE".

Comment: doesnt make a difference in this case as only small amounts of data i guess, i was just curious

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create for more info

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find_or_create_by_` method:

```
Fixture.find_or_create_by_home_team(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, fixture_date: date, kickoff_time: kick_off)
```

This dynamic finder can be used to create the object if it doesn’t already exist. This dynamic finder is called with find_or_create_by_ and will return the object if it already exists and otherwise creates it, then returns it.

If you have additional parameters to find_or_create_by_, you have to pass all the parameters as a hash.